# Multiple parameter in HTTP post request not Binding in Asp.net webApi 2.0

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, angular5, typescript-2.5

I have created a sample for post multiple params in HTTP Request.But i can't able to assign the value in Web Api Controller. Please check the below code.

**.ts**

```
deleteEntry(entryId: number, entryActiveFlag: string): Observable<number> {
        let dataUrl = `http/localhost:8080/Entry/DeleteEntry`;
        let params = { entryId, entryActiveFlag};
        //params.append(entryId);
        //params.append('entryActiveFlag', entryActiveFlag);
        let body = JSON.stringify(params );
        return this.http.post(dataUrl, body)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
    }
```

**.WebApi**

```
 [HttpPost("DeleteEntry")]
    public  IActionResult DeleteEntry([FromBody]int entryId,string entryActiveFlag)
    {
        return Ok( _service.DeleteEntry(entryId, entryActiveFlag));
    }
```

Comment: What is the response of your request? Does it result in an error? Does DeleteEntry actually get hit?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg  Yes, DeleteEntry was hit but the sending value is not binding in the paramters. The entryId getting as 0 and entryActiveFlag getting as null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the input details in one class and provide the class object as parameter to Web API method.
In your case you can add below class -

```
public class EntryDetails
{
  public int EntryId {get;set;}

  public bool EntryActiveFlag

}
```

And your web method will be

```
[HttpPost("DeleteEntry")]
    public  IActionResult DeleteEntry(EntryDetails entryDetails)
    {
        return Ok( _service.DeleteEntry(entryDetails.EntryId, entryDetails.EntryActiveFlag));
    }
```

Accordingly also change the invocation from client method.

Comment: Yes, I already tried with this, It's Working fine but i like to know how to pass in parameters. Why it's not passing in the parameter? Is i did somewhere wrong or any other reason?

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
let body = "entryId=23&entryActiveFlag=true";
let options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
};
     return this.http.post(dataUrl, body,options )
                .map(res => res.json())
                .catch(this.handleError);
```

Or 
try below code

```
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append("key","value");
let options = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
};

 return this.http.post(dataUrl, formData,options )
            .map(res => res.json())
            .catch(this.handleError);
```